# What is your favorite/preferred road shoe?

Tags: product-rec, road-bike, shoes

I recently purchased [Specialized Sport MTB Shoe](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCEqProduct.jsp?spid=52068&menuItemId=9309&eid=4927) for my [Dual Shimano pedals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002NVJEOM).  Love the clipless pedals, but this specific shoe seems to rub/apply pressure to both my big toes after a long ride.

They fit, but I think the tip of the shoe is too tough, or made cheaply.  They only cost $90, so I thought I might need to invest in a lighter, softer, more expensive shoe.  I have been using them for about a month everyday to work/back, and weekend rides, figured they're broken-in enough.

Not really sure, and I know the community here will be able to help.  Which is your preferred, favorite?

Comment: can someone add the tag "shoes", dont have enough rep, maybe even a favorite tag

Comment: favorite, not favourite, unless it does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

My preferred cycling shoes are the ones that feel good and I can stand to be in all day. Currently for road cycling I have Specialized and before that it was Sidi. I have some Shimano mountain bike shoes for commuting. I have no idea what I'll buy the next time.

I'm a bit obsessive about shoe fit so I usually wind up trying on several pairs before I walk out of the LBS with a pair of shoes. One thing is that I ignore brands other than as an indication of quality and previous experience. Two, I start out by trying on the same model I have if I liked it. Three, I compare at least 2 others. And also, look at the shoe as to quality and construction.

Comment: Just to say... Cycling shoes are a bit of a moving target, I loved my last pair of Sidis', but couldn't replace them because the model was discontinued. And also, cycling shoes are completely personal in terms of fit, comfort, etc

Answer (score 3):

I've always come back to SIDI shoes no matter how many other pairs I've tried on. Been almost 10 years with a pair of SIDI shoes powering my cycling.

Comment: im leaning towards SIDI, but they're pricey

Comment: they certainly are. last time I looked for 2 months and it came down to the most expensive SIDI's shoes again. They were just the most comfortable and for 1000KM+ a month that's all that matters.

Comment: I bought the expensive SIDI shoes.  I tried a lot on, but these fit *perfectly*.  Since they're rigid, I can expect that fit to last a long time too.  I wouldn't put too much into the brand other than quality of materials.  Quality of fit is the most important factor and that can only be figured out by trying them all on.

Comment: I have tried many different brands over the past 20 years and now I just buy Sidi's. They come in widths (great for people with wide feet like me) and are durable and comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought a second pair of Bontrager Street shoes to replace my first pair. They're comfortable, they come with removable, customizable insoles. They're leather and thus pretty waterproof unless the rain's really heavy. They've got recessed cleats so I never need to change my shoes when I get to my destination. They also look quite nice.

Thinking about it, since I cycle to work and then don't change them, I spend most of my waking hours wearing them!

Answer (score 1):

I have two pairs of road shoes - the SPDs on my commute bikes (because I need to clip in and out a lot and possibly to walk around at the end of the ride) are very comfortable ... and are exactly what you have. You could take a more precise look at the setup - if you move the cleat slightly, perhaps the location of some application of undue pressure might shift and relieve the toes?

Comment: maybe..my best guess is the geometry of the shoe. So I was thinking of trying on different brands, etc., thanks for the input